# Python: How to slice string next to input data

Tags: python, string

I have the task to do but I don't know how can I start.
In output I need to give back day name and number.

I know how to get the day name but I can't find how to get number either.
Could you suggest me something.

Data for the task:

```
data = (
data = """
monday;1250
tuesday;1405
wednesday;1750
thursday;1100
friday;0800
saturday;1225
sunday;1355
"""
```

My uncompleted code:

```
day = input("Insert day: ").lower()

if day in data:
    print("""The day is "{}"\nThe number is: """.format(dzien))
```

The output should looks like:

```
The day is "day name"
The number is "number"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could parse your data into a dictionary and then look up the corresponding number:

```py
data = """
monday;1250
tuesday;1405
wednesday;1750
thursday;1100
friday;0800
saturday;1225
sunday;1355
"""

data = {day: number for day, number in [line.split(';') for line in data.strip().split('\n')]}

day = input("Insert day: ").lower()

if day in data:
    print(f"""The day is "{day}"\nThe number is: {data[day]}""")
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I have one more question. Does it possible to assign that "data[day]" to variable? I need to do some simply calculation with that number but when I create variable value = data[day] it does not work. I get error message

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct then to conclude this particular question. If you have additional questions, it would be best to create a new question with an equally nice write up (including the error message). Right now, I can only tell you that an assignment in the form of ```user_number = data[day]``` should work if used in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Convert data into dictionary:

```
data = {'monday' : '1250', 
        'tuesday': '1405', 
        'wednesday': '1750', 
        'thursday':'1100',
        'friday': '0800',
        'saturday':'1225',
        'sunday':'1355'}


day = input("Insert day: ").lower()

if day in data:
   print(f'The day is "{day}"\nThe number is: "{data[day]}"')
```

Comment: Thank you. I know how to deal with it if it would be the dictionary but the task is different.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary. Dictionaries allow to organize data in key-value format, so you can access to the information binded to the day with data[day]. Change the code to:

```
data = {
    'monday': 1250,
    'tuesday': 1405,
    'wednesday': 1750,
    'thursday': 1100,
    'friday': 800,
    'saturday': 1225,
    'sunday': 1355
}

day = input("Insert day: ").lower()

if day in data:
    # get number associated with day
    day_number = data[day] 
    # print output
    print('The day is "{}".\nThe number is "{}".'.format(day, day_number))
```

It will print:

```
Insert day: monday
The day is "monday".
The number is "1250".
```

Comment: Thank you. I know how to deal with it if it would be the dictionary but the task is different.

Comment: Ok sorry i missunderstood your question. To convert your text to dictionary, use:

data = dict([cur_el.split(';') for cur_el in data.strip().split('\n')])